# Datatables column filtering with icons

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I try to filter a specific column with a dropdown in datatables with icons in it. Everything works fine with a text box but not with a select-box.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuMYa.png)

I also set up a jsfiddle, but couldnt get it to run:

```
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eyk107/uvznse86/
```

I only want to filter the icons by the icons-title or alt.
Thank you in advance.

BR
Eyk

Answer (score 0):

Add picture for better understanding:

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak1qz.png)